# Formatting fprintf

Tags: matlab, printf

I have a bit of Matlab code and I am trying to export some string and create a tab-delimitted text file from it.  I think fprintf performs similarly in C (if not please edit my tag).  I believe my issue is with my format string.  Basically I have 7 strings that I want separated by tabs and then a newline character.  please note that "fid" is a full path.  I am looping this in a for loop so lines are being appended each pass and the file is built.

```
ImgData = strcat(ImgData, fid, '\t', imgNumber, '\t', N_std,'\t',S,'\t',N,'\t',SNR,'\t',SNR_dB,'\n');
DataOut = fopen(strcat('Image_F', folderNumber, '_Data.txt'), 'w');
fprintf(DataOut,'%s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\n',ImgData);
```

You may be curious on how this exports.  This formats like

```
fid\tI#\tN_std\tS\tN\tSNR\tSNR_dB\n
```

in the txt file.  As you can tell this isn't tab-delimitted which my major issue.  I am having some trouble with the format string.  Does anyone know how to reformat it so it prints the tabs and newline?

Comment: removed C/C++ tags - the code in question is matlab only, no?

Comment: and, more important, what is your question? what is the problem? expected output? minimal code that can reproduce the problem?

Comment: I am pretty sure that fprintf is taken directly from C++ so I re-added the C++ tag. My problem is that it prints non tab delimited.  The tabs print as a string instead of tabs.

Comment: @MatthewKemnetz if you follow that reasoning, I can tag any question regarding printf C/C++/Matlab/Java/Lisp and any other language using printf like format strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a string in `ImgData` that you then pass as input to `fprintf`. This reads `ImgData` into the first `%s` of the format string, and then adds at least one tab at the end.

What you should do instead is write something like:

```
`fprintf(DataOut,'%s\t%i\n',imgName,imgNumber)`
```

which assumes that `imgName` is a string and `imgNumber` an integer number. Note that I pass two placeholders (with the %-sign) and two input variables to fprintf.

Use `%6.2f` print floating point numbers with a total of 6 characters, including 2 after the comma, for `SNR`, for example.

For easier development, you can drop the first input argument to `fprintf`, in which case it will print to command line.